# jQuery Multiply input value and sum with another input

Tags: jquery

I've been trying to get this relatively simple function to work and it won't. It keeps outputting the numbers as a string instead of adding them together.

```
$('#FS-quantity-1').change(function() {
            var subtotal = $("#HF-quantity").val()*2;
            var sum = Number(subtotal)+$("#FS-quantity-1").val();
            $("#sticker-quantity").val(sum);
        });
```

This outputs the 2 values together as a string instead of adding them together. Also tried this:

```
$('#FS-quantity-1').change(function() {
            var subtotal = $("#HF-quantity").val()*2;
            var sum = parseInt(subtotal)+$("#FS-quantity-1").val();
            $("#sticker-quantity").val(sum);
        });
```

And that didn't work either. I also tried multiplying subtotal by 1 to convert it to an integer. That didn't work.

Any ideas how I can get subtotal and the val() of #FS-quantity-1 to sum as an integer?

Comment: parse both fields into int?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
var sum = subtotal + parseInt($("#FS-quantity-1").val(), 10);
```

You don't need to use `Number` on `subtotal` because it's already a number, due to the multiplication that was used to assign it. But `.val()` returns a string, and you need to convert that to a number, because `+` performs concatenation if either of the arguments is a string.

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks! I knew that the 2 amounts were being concatenated, but I couldn't figure out which one was the string. Thanks again.

Comment: You should have looked at them in the Javascript debugger. It will put quotes around the string.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. I'm not that good in the browser's JS debugger. Need to get better at that. :)

Answer (score 0):

Is the value you are getting from #HF-quantity a string or integer?

You should maybe do something like this. Not saying this is the solution but its more readable.

```
var addThis = $("#element").val();
var plusThis = $("#otherElemenet").val();

var total = addThis + plusThis;
```

Comment: I agree. I should get in the habit of setting variables at the beginning. Thanks.

Comment: This might be more readable, but it definitely doesn't solve the problem. `.val()` returns a string, and `+` concatenates them instead of adding them.