# Add variables to javascript price quote/form

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to add variables as such to my price calculator at the minute it takes to value entered and multiplies this by 0.15.

I am  trying to make so if value between 0 - 1000 then multiply this by 0.15 
Then if value between 1001-2000 multiply this by 0.06 for example.

My javascript currently:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calculatePrice').click(function() {
        var sheets = $('#sheets').val();
        var price = (sheets * 0.15);
        $('.price').html('Estimated Price: &pound;'  + price);
    });
});
```

Comment: does this work or not ?

Comment: Have you heard of [conditionals](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/221/conditions/819/if-else-if-else-control#t=201610121750473015712)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Multiply input value and sum with another input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25212647/jquery-multiply-input-value-and-sum-with-another-input)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's just multiplication you want,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calculatePrice').click(function() {
        var sheets = $('#sheets').val(), price;
        if(sheets < 1000) {price = (sheets * 0.15)}
        else if( sheets < 2000) { price = (sheets * 0.6)}
        // And any more conditions you want to add
        $('.price').html('Estimated Price: &pound;'  + price);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not very complex.

just put your condition hold the value and do multiplication

here `+` is used before variable name to convert value from `string` to `int`.

Try like this

```
var ratio=1;
if(+sheets<=1000)
 ratio=0.15;
else if (+sheets<=2000 )
 ratio=0.06;
var price = +sheets*ratio;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calculatePrice').click(function() {
        var sheets = $('#sheets').val();
        var price = sheets <= 1000 ? sheets * 0.15 : sheets * 0.06;
        $('.price').html('Estimated Price: &pound;'  + price);
    });
});
```

This will multiply anything less than 1000 by .15 and anything over 1000 by .06
If you need to add a range over 2000 then you'll be best off adding some if statements like this:

```
var price = null;
if(sheets <= 1000) price = sheets * .15;
else if(sheets > 1000 && sheets < 2000) price = sheets * .06;
```

Then you can add more ranges above 2000, but you definitely need an else in this example in case the price is over 2000

Comment: you don't need to use `sheets`  mutiple time .. `var price = sheets *( sheets <= 1000 ? 0.15 : 0.06);`